# Removing the filesystem quota on a partition

Tags: 12.04, fstab, dovecot, quota

I want to install Dovecot on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and it recommends that we place the control files into a partition which will not be limited by the filesystem quota.

If I create an ext4 partition with 2 gigs, how do I remove the quota on that partition? I know the partitions are defined in /etc/fstab, and I think `usrquota` and `grpquota` have to be explicitly set to disabled.

But I am unsure what the entire line should look like.

Is it something like:

```
/dev/hda2       /       ext4    defaults,usrquota,grpquota        1       0        0
```

On the other hand, [I found something](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/quotaon.8.html) called `quotaon` and `quotaoff`. Would this be used instead of fstab? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your mount points are defined in `/etc/fstab` and those options will be used by default every time you boot.

So if you use the line:

```
 /dev/hda2       /       ext4    defaults,usrquota,grpquota        1       0        0
```

quotas will be enabled when you boot.

The commands `quotaon` and `quotaoff` will enable / disable quotas from the command line.

See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man8/quotaon.8.html for additional options.

So if you wish to disable quotas by default, use `noquota` in fstab

```
/dev/hda2       /       ext4    defaults,noquota        1       0        0
```

Comment: Could you clarify something for me. The fourth column in /etc/fstab represents mount options. There are two different types: FILESYSTEM INDEPENDENT/DEPENDENT SPECIFIC MOUNT OPTIONS. `quotaoff` is not an option in either of those. But I do see `grpquota|noquota|quota|usrquota ` in the DEPENDENT option, however it also says this: `These options are accepted but ignored. `

Comment: I found the description of mount options here: http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount

Comment: Read the entire line, lol -  "These options are accepted but ignored. (`However, quota utilities may react to such strings in /etc/fstab`.) " So mount will ignore these strings, but quota uses them.

Comment: Whoops, why did I miss that. Thank you, I think I understand it.

Comment: I guess as a curiosity question: does using quotaon/quotaoff just modify /etc/fstab to use `noquota`? What would be the benefit of using this command rather than manually specifying it in /etc/fstab?

Comment: That I know, the commands do not affect fstab. I would imagine you use those commands to enable or disable quotas "on the fly". So the defautl behavior of quota is set in fstab, and modified on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Quotas are off by default, and must be explicitly enabled by building quota files with `quotacheck`, and placing the quota flags in /etc/fstab for `quotaon -a` to recognize and activate the quotas during boot.

So unless you did all that, you don't have to do a thing.

If you did, then you can turn them off with `quotaoff` and removing the flags from /etc/fstab to prevent them from being turned back on at the next boot.